# Shiny: How to filter data based on location of user input data

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, ggmap

I have a shiny app running [here](https://sillasgonzaga.shinyapps.io/aptsnorio/). It plots around 12 thousand apartments and rooms for rent on a leaflet interactive map and adds a marker on the map based on the address that the user inputs. Here's the [code](https://github.com/sillasgonzaga/olxshiny). Sorry for the if it is not well documented.

There are two different data frame objects: one is for apartments (`df.apt`) and the other is for rooms(`df.quartos`).

However, because of the amount of data the app loads, it is a bit slow. I want to add a resource that will plot the data only after the user inserts the address and also choose a proximity range (like, show only the apartments within 10km from the inputed address). How should I go about it?

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
library(ggmap)


source("post4-prepararshiny.R") #loads data and helper functions


 ui = bootstrapPage(
   div(class = "outer",
       tags$head(
         # Include our custom CSS
         includeCSS("styles.css"),
         includeScript("gomap.js")
       ),

   tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
   leafletOutput("mymap", width = "100%", height = "100%"),

   absolutePanel(id = "controls",# class = "panel panel-default",
                 fixed = TRUE,
                 draggable = TRUE,
                 top = 60, left = "auto", right = 20, bottom = "auto",
                 width = 330, height = "auto",

                 h2("Buscador OLX"),
                 textInput(inputId = "userlocation",
                           label = "Digite um endereço\n com pelo menos rua, número, bairro e cidade",
                           value = ""),
                 helpText("Exemplo: Rua Dias da Rocha, 85 - Copacabana, Rio de Janeiro - RJ"),

                 sliderInput(inputId = "distancia", label = "Escolha a distância em km:",
                             min = 0, max = 30, value = 15),

                 actionButton("go", "Buscar"),
                 helpText("Encontre imóveis para alugar perto de onde você quiser!"),

                 helpText("Cada ponto no mapa representa um imóvel para alugar.",
                          "A cor de um ponto é determinada pelo valor do aluguel.",
                          "Clique em um ponto para ter mais informações sobre o imóvel."),

                 helpText("Mais informações sobre este app em sillasgonzaga.github.io")

                 )

   ),
   tags$div(id="cite",
            'Dados extraídos do OLX em 12/11/2016.', ' Contato: sillasgonzaga.github.io'
   )
)
```

## server.R

```
server = function(input, output, session){

  #browser()
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    map <- leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.BlackAndWhite") %>%
    # coordenadas de um ponto em específico
    addMarkers(lat = -22.911872, lng = -43.230184,
               popup = "Estádio do Maracanã! <br> Apenas um exemplo!") %>%


    # plotar apartamentos
    addCircleMarkers(data = df.apt,
                     lng = ~lon, lat = ~lat,
                     color = ~vetorCoresApt(preco),
                     opacity = 1.5,
                     popup = textoPopup(df.apt, "apartamento"),
                     # Definir nome do grupo para ser usado na camada
                     group = "Apartamentos") %>%
    # plotar quartos
    addCircleMarkers(data = df.quartos,
                     lng = ~lon, lat = ~lat,
                     color = ~vetorCoresQuarto(preco),
                     opacity = 1.5,
                     popup = textoPopup(df.quartos, "quarto"),
                     group = "Quartos") %>%
    addLayersControl(
      overlayGroups = c("Apartamentos", "Quartos"),
      options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE),
      position = "bottomright"
    ) %>%
    addLegend(pal = vetorCoresApt, values = df.apt$preco,
              position = "bottomright")
    map
  })


   observeEvent(input$go, {
     v <- geocode(input$userlocation)
     leafletProxy('mymap', session) %>% addMarkers(lng = v$lon,lat = v$lat)
   })


}
```

I know that I can use the function `geosphere::distm()` to compute the distance between a matrix of data and a data point like:

```
coord <- matrix(data = c(df.apt$lon, df.apt$lat), ncol = 2)
distance_vector <- distm(x = coord, y = c(lon = -43.183447, lat = -22.913912), fun = distVincentySphere)
# insert vector into data frame
df.apt$distance <- distance_vector
```

However, how do I do this in an reactive way that will allow me to change the `distance` column every time the users click the button and change the `sliderInput()` that will be used to indicate the range of proximity?

P.S.: Sorry for code and comments in portuguese.

## EDIT: SOLVED

I was able to come up with a solution after @HubertL reply. Here's what I did at `server.R`:

```
  distance_apt_reactive <- eventReactive(input$go, { 
    address_latlon <- geocode(input$userlocation)
    dist <- distm(x = matrix(data = c(df.apt$lon, df.apt$lat), ncol = 2), 
                  y = c(lon = address_latlon$lon, lat = address_latlon$lat), 
                  fun = distVincentySphere)
    dist <- dist/1000

  })

  apt_reactive <- reactive({df.apt[distance_reactive() < input$distancia,]})

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    map <- leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.BlackAndWhite") %>%
      setView(lng = mean(df.apt$lon), lat = mean(df.apt$lat), zoom = 11) %>%
      addLegend(pal = vetorCoresApt, values = df.apt$preco,
                position = "bottomright",
                layerId = "legend")

  map  
  })

     observe({
       leafletProxy("mymap") %>%
         clearMarkers() %>%
         #addMarkers(lng = myadress()$lon, lat = myadress()$lat) %>%
         addCircleMarkers(data = apt_reactive(),
                          lng = ~lon, lat = ~lat,
                          color = ~vetorCoresQuarto(preco),
                          opacity = 1.5,
                          # adicionar popup
                          popup = textoPopup(apt_reactive(), "apartamento"),
                          group = "Apartamentos")
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `reactive` that would filter your `data.frame` based on the distance to the address :

```
apt_reactive <- reactive({ 
    address_latlon <- geocode(input$userlocation)
    dist <- distm(x = matrix(data = c(df.apt$lon, df.apt$lat), ncol = 2), 
                  y = c(lon = address_latlon$lon, lat = address_latlon$lat), 
                  fun = distVincentySphere)
    apt.df[dist < input$distancia,]
})
```

Then replace

```
addCircleMarkers(data = df.apt
```

by

```
addCircleMarkers(data = apt_reactive()
```

(and repeat same process with `quartos_reactive` for `df.quartos`)

Comment: Your solution is pretty good but there's still  a problem. Every time the user changes the distance range, a new map will be rended by `renderLeaflet()`, which slows down the app. Is there any way to make more smooth? I wonder if this has anything to do with `leafletProxy()`.

Comment: Yes but because there will be much less point to render, it will be very quick. But you are right,it is probably possible to use `leafletProxy`. I'll have a look at this (new to me) function

Comment: So, I did a lot of testing here and it seems that I want is simply impossible. Imagine that you select 3 km as the distance range. It will plot only the data within that range. If I use the slider to increase this range to 10 km, it will plot the new data included in this new range. However, the problem is, if I slide it back to 3 km, the data within 10 km will not disappear. Instead, it will plot the data that was already ploted. Please let me know if I'm not being clear.